# search and filter function by laravel

Tags: laravel

i have User model that have many to many relation with Area model and the Area Model have one to many relation with City Model and i want to filter users by city

```
public function search(Request $request){    
return User::where('status', 1)->where('type', User::TYPE_INSTRUCTOR)
            ->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
                if($request->city){
                    $areas = Area::where('city_id',$request->city)->get();
                    foreach($areas as $area){
                        $query->area($area);
                    } 
                }
                if ($request->area) {
                    $query->area($request->area);
                }
            })
            ->orderBy('id')->paginate(8);
}
```

and i make this function in User model

```
public function scopeArea($query, $search){
    $query->whereHas('areas', function (Builder $query) use ($search){
        $query->where('area_id', $search);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the problem by add this cas

```
if($request->city){
                $areas = Area::where('city_id',$request->city)->pluck('id')->toArray();

                $query->whereHas('areas', function (Builder $query) use ($areas){
                    $query->whereIn('area_id', $areas);
                });
                
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code for filtering

```
 $query = DB::table('users')
            ->leftjoin('areas','users.id', '=' , 'areas.user_id')
            ->leftjoin('cities','areas.id', '=' , 'cities.areas_id');
        if(!empty($cityId)){
            $query->where('cities.id','=' , $cityId);
        }
        $result = $query->get();
```

Comment: there isn't column areas.user_id ...... my tables are " users , cities , areas , area_user

Comment: how did you make the relationship with area and model

Comment: many to many with pivot table area_user

Comment: can you kindly provide the er diagram these tables